# File watch on texture images from disk?

Tags: texturing, image

Is there is a way to use a texture on disk and have Blender periodically update that texture if the file on disk changes.

I'm trying to paint layers in Gimp and overwrite the file on disk and get quicker feedback on how it looks in the viewport.